# pointer to function compilation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to call the function using the pointer to function above but it keeps showing this error:expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type. any help?

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class a
{
public:
    a(){}
    int f(float m){cout<<"called.\n";return 1;}
};

int main()
{
    int (a::*ptr2)(float m) = &a::f;
    a *p ,obj;
    p = &obj;
    obj.*ptr2(.8);
    p->*ptr2(.5);
}
```

Comment: Try `(obj.*ptr2)(.8);` and `(p->*ptr2)(.5);`.

Comment: This code **does not use a pointer to function**. It uses a **pointer to member function**. They are two completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing some parenthesis around your function pointer calls.

```
#include<iostream>

class a
{
public:
    a(){}
    int f(float m) {
        std::cout<<"called."<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int (a::*ptr2)(float m) = &a::f;
    a *p ,obj;
    p = &obj;
    (obj.*ptr2)(.8); //note the difference
    (p->*ptr2)(.5);
}
```

It is in situations like this that `std::invoke` can be extremely handy:  [std::invoke Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

Comment: +1, but `std::function` is not a good candidate for situations like this, it is unnecessary overhead.  This does not require type erasure, if you are looking to make this syntactically pleasing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke is one option that does not involve virtual dispatch

Comment: @Curious No disagreement there, though I would argue that in an example as simple as this one the difference is negligible. But in terms of long term best practices you are correct.

Comment: Edited your answer to reflect that!  Didn't want OP to tread down the wrong path..